# Stop facetime video pausing when switching spaces

Tags: macos, mojave, facetime

When I facetime call from my macbook (macOS Mojave) how can I stop the facetime video from turning off when I switch spaces (especially to full-screened apps, especially Safari)?

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I have found for this is to assign FaceTime to All Desktops.  In the Dock, right-click on the FaceTime app icon and under `Options`, assign it to `All Desktops`.  This really shouldn't be necessary and Apple should fix this in FaceTime.  It does appear that the desktop assignment persists even after quitting FaceTime, so that helps.

EDIT: You must have multiple spaces already created for the `All Desktops` option to be available.

Comment: That doesn't seem to exist for me. The only Options are Keep in Dock, Open at Login, Show in Finder

Comment: @theonlygusti - interesting.  I have multiple monitors, so perhaps those options are only available when using multiple monitors.  When I tested, I switched between spaces on a single monitor using FaceTime and it worked (while I had multiple monitors active).  But I have not tried this when using only a single screen with no other monitors connected. At a minimum, I would expect you need to have already created two spaces.

Comment: @theonlygusti - This apple support page seems to indicate you need only have multiple spaces and not multiple monitors: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/12.0/mac/12.0

Comment: This is all i can see https://i.stack.imgur.com/87oVi.png

Comment: Oh nevermind, I found it if I make a new Desktop. Sorry, I can see that you wrote that but I didn't quite understand that previously. I'll see if this works on my next call, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: It doesn't work when I switch to a full-screened app.